# C# - Navigate to a XAML page inside a folder

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I am an UWP app, and I want organize my code and all my files (XAML and C# files of my app). Can I put XAML files inside a folder?
If yes, I use this to navigate to another XAML page: `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(XamlPage));`
And if I put the XAML file inside a folder, how can I solve this?

Something like this?
`this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FolderName.XamlPage));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a page inside a new folder, it will be inside a namespace of the same name. So supposing your app is called `MyApp` and your folder is `FolderName`, the namespace is `MyApp.FolderName`.

You can then put a using statement on top of the page:

```
using MyApp.FolderName;
```

And then you can normally navigate:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(XamlPage));
```

Comment: Sure thing :-) ! Happy coding!